# Creating html table from .json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Javascript and angular and I am trying to create an html table to look similar to the below from a .json file using angular:

BALLERI BB 990063
Date  33589  33590  33591
Immed  1836   1848   1860
01/15                1861
01/30                1862

STYLENAME2 BLK
Date M080  M085   M090
Immed  12           11 
01/15        12     12 
01/30               13

```
{styleName:"BALLERI BB",                                        
colorCode:"90063",                                             
colorDesc:"PINK",                                              
construction:"81707",                                          
patternDesc:"ZAXY BALLERINA BABY",                             
constDesc:" ",                                                 
prodLine:"ZAXY",                                               
prodCat:"KID",                                                 
yys:"20161",                                                   
price:"        14.00",                                         
msrp:"         0.00",                                          
sizeDates:[  
{                                                                
avSize:"33589",                                                
isCase:"Y",                                                    
caseQty: 12,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"IMMED",                                                
avQty:     1836                                                
}                                                                
]                                                                
},
{                                                                
avSize:"33590",                                                
isCase:"Y",                                                    
caseQty: 12,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"IMMED",                                                
avQty:     1848                                                
}                                                                
]                                                                
},
{                                                                
avSize:"33591",                                                
isCase:"Y",                                                    
caseQty: 12,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"IMMED",                                                
avQty:     1860                                                
},{                                                                
avDate:"01/15",                                                
avQty:     1861                                                
},
{                                                                
avDate:"01/30",                                                
avQty:     1862                                                
}                                                                                 
]                                                                
}               
]  
},
{styleName:"STYLENAME2",                                        
colorCode:"BLK",                                             
colorDesc:"BLACK",                                              
construction:"81717",                                          
patternDesc:"PATTERN DESC FOR STYLENAME2",                             
constDesc:" ",                                                 
prodLine:"ZAXY",                                               
prodCat:"KID",                                                 
yys:"20161",                                                   
price:"        14.00",                                         
msrp:"         55.00",                                          
sizeDates:[  
{                                                                
avSize:"M080",                                                
isCase:"N",                                                    
caseQty: 1,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"IMMED",                                                
avQty:     12                                                
}                                                                
]                                                                
},
{                                                                
avSize:"M085",                                                
isCase:"N",                                                    
caseQty: 1,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"01/15",                                                
avQty:     12                                                
}                                                                
]                                                                
},
{                                                                
avSize:"M090",                                                
isCase:"N",                                                    
caseQty: 1,                                                   
dates:[                                                        
{                                                                
avDate:"IMMED",                                                
avQty:     11                                                
},{                                                                
avDate:"01/15",                                                
avQty:     12                                                
},
{                                                                
avDate:"01/30",                                                
avQty:     13                                                
}                                                                                 
]                                                                
}               
]  
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not for doing your job for you. It's for helping you to understand how you can do it by yourself. Try to simplify and format properly your json. And ask about an approach rather than about final solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you're requesting data from a JSON file, then adding the data into tables. The example below shows how to get data from a file named "dataName.json" then stores the content in "$scope.tableContents"

```
$scope.tableContents;

$http.get('dataSrc/dataName.json')
 .then(function successCallback(data){
    $scope.tableContents = data;
     }, function errorCallback(err){
        console.log(err);
 });
```

You must have added `$scope` and `$http` to your controller then make use of angular's ng-repeat directive to help you format your data. Read the full doc here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: The `.success` method has been deprecated see the notice -- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Comment: @georgeawg ok, i'll refactor my example with the new method. Thanks for the info